# pool heat pump wiring instructions DOEL 19000btu, 5.56 kw, 220v single phase

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v, heat-pump

I am trying in install Doel UHP056CS, **name tag says 220 volts**, however it comes with a pigtail already wired with a standard 110v male cord.
Power Input label L, N, Ground,  (three connectors)
Water Pump Input label  1 and 2 (two connectors)
DOEL very poor to no service.

My main is standard 200 amp service, L1, L2, Common

Comment: Can you include a picture of the cord and plug?  It's possible that it is a NEMA 6 (240V) plug.  At a quick glance, they can look close enough to a NEMA 5 (120V) to be confusing if you don't pay close attention to the direction of the blades.

Comment: Pictures will be nice.  Trying to wire what I assume is a European device to American electric system can make life difficult.  Can sometimes work, but other times needs major adaptions.  If it is a NEMA 6 then life is easy.

Comment: Update to my above comment: I just looked up this product/company.  Looks a bit sketchy to me - is there a UL or ETL listing anywhere on this product?  Their product listings don't seem to have much or any detail.

Comment: I found multiple reviews that say it comes with a 120V plug but requires 220V.

Comment: @longneck That's typical for shady China products, as China used the US 120 V NEMA 1 plug for 240 V until they changed to one that's similar to Australia's beginning in 2008. The installed base of NEMA-style sockets and multi-standard sockets means it still appears.

Comment: I got 0 results in Google for the model claimed. After correcting the "O" (oh) to a "0" (nought/zero), I got, astoundingly, 6 results (far, far, far, far too few to be normal; there should be tens of thousands for almost any keyword).  The few are: Amazon, eBay, Walmart (duplicating Amazon), and "uBuy" - all sellers of cheap Cheese junk. The website looks "hastily put up by English-as-second-language foreigners", odd font and the claimed street address is a generic industrial building in L.A. with no sign. **The phone number is Detroit, WTF**.  The whole thing seems sketch.

Comment: I checked California corporations DB, no such entity doing business in the state, certainly not leasing buildings. And like user71659 says, supplying equipment with an inappropriate NEMA 5-15 plug *is a signature move* for the shadiest makers of Cheese counterfeits who sit behind the Red Curtain, un-sue-able. Your only recourse is probably the 30-day return window Amazon *makes them give you*. And in the future, buy from reputable suppliers. Note: actually the finest and most modern-design heat pumps are made in Asia (not stodgy old American manufacturers) but this doesn't seem to be that.

Comment: Also their email address is the domain of "Chengdu Tops" a different retail website that uses the same template but claims to to be located in Sichuan (implied: China).  They make video booths.

Comment: Are you dead-set on using the piece of cheese you are originally thinking of, or is getting something more fit for purpose an option?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test out a second unit that I had gotten from a customer and sure enough, I cut off the 110v plug off of the pigtail and connected it to a 220v breaker.
Black 110v white 110v and the green to ground and it worked. I simulated a pool pump by connecting a pump I have in the garage and after a short time out period it started as expected and ran well. It took a little bit to heat up the 15 gallons of cold tap water but it did  warm up the water in the drum to much warmer than when I started.
The tech support from DOEL communicated to me via whatsapp but the info they gave me about the electrical was inaccurate and not correct based on US standards.

Comment: Stupid question  did you try it at 110V?  Maybe the label is wrong

Comment: Are you and Jim craig the same person?  If so, merge your accounts.